# elasticsearch php client range filter issue

Tags: php, elasticsearch, filter, range

i dont get this range filter to work with the elasticsearch php client:

```
Array ( 
[index] => xyz
[type] => imagesearch 
[body] => Array ( 
   [from] => 0 
   [size] => 10 
   [query] => Array ( 
      [filtered] => Array ( 
          [filter] => Array ( 
             [bool] => Array ( 
               [must] => Array ( 
                 [term] => Array ( 
                    [type] => abc 
                    [stationId] => 01
               ) 
               [range] => Array ( 
                    [timestamp] => Array ( 
                       [gt] => 1449356400 
                       ) 
                    )
               ) 
          ) 
       ) 
       [query] => Array ( 
          [match] => Array (
            [_all] => Hund 
          ) 
       ) 
     ) 
   ) 
)
```

)

without the range filter the query/filter works fine. what am i missing?

Comment: Please provide exception message that you are getting.

Comment: Please also provide the raw query instead of the php array syntax or at least tell us which lib you are using.

Comment: what is the `mapping` of field timestamp?

Comment: error looks like that: SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed; shardFailures {[Acb6rFhHSJ2zKr282YRz_g][xyz][0]: SearchParseException[[xyz][0]: from[0],size[10]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\"from\":0,\"size\":\"10\",\"query\":{\"filtered\":{\"filter\":{\"bool\":{\"must\":{\"term\":{\"type\":\"abc\",\"stationId\":\"01\"},\"range\":{\"timestamp\":{\"gt\":1449356400}}}}}

i use https://github.com/madewithlove/elasticsearcher, but with a native query in this case.

Comment: In your `term` query, the `type` property is not recognized. Just remove that and it will work.

Comment: Also, I think you want your range filter to be contained within your `must` array (or `should` or `filter` (>2.0) arrays).

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch (backed by Java) uses different format for timestamp. Instead of seconds it uses miliseconds, so you have to multiply your timestamp by 1000.

To solve problems like these there are [abstraction levels](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/php-api/current/_community_dsls.html) for PHP and [integrations for frameworks](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/php-api/current/_community_integrations.html).